# Top Down Parser Grammar Recovery

Tags: parsing, grammar, topdown

I'm learning about parsing and I've written a recursive descent parser that automatically removes left recursion (using [standard methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion)). This produces a weakly equivalent grammar and introduces new non-terminals. Is there a good description of a method to convert an accepted parse-tree produced by this method back to the original grammar?